Как создать несколько мостов на один сетевой интерфейс в Ubuntu?
Мне нужно поднять несколько PPPOE на одной сетевухе, но с разных Мак адресов.
Логично сделать это через сетевые мосты.
auto enp42s0
iface enp42s0 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet manual
        bridge_ports enp42s0
        hwaddress e2:3f:26:5c:8d:45
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0
        bridge_maxwait 0

auto br1
iface br1 inet manual
        bridge_ports enp42s0
        hwaddress e2:3f:26:5c:8d:44
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0
        bridge_maxwait 0

auto br2
iface br2 inet manual
        bridge_ports enp42s0
        hwaddress e2:3f:26:5c:8d:43
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0
        bridge_maxwait 0

прописываю это в intarfaces, но PPPOE получается поднять только на одном из этих мостов, остальные в ip link показывают "NO-CARRIER".
Пробовал через brctl addif, но ошибка по итогу.

Как правильно настроить?

Мосты тут не совсем в тему. Для поднятия нескольких мак на одной карточке используют mactap или macvlan драйвер.
ip link add link enp42s0 address 00:11:11:11:11:11 macvlan0 type macvlan
ip link set macvlan0 up

В Вашем случае macvlan предпочтительней.
